# Google API - Access Calendar via Service Account

Tags: php, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

I keep getting this fatal error.

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_IO_Exception' with message 'HTTP Error: Unable to connect: 'fopen(https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token): failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. ''

I am accessing it by a localhost on another computer using my network. I just attempted to reboot it and see it that solved it by some weird means. Did not work.

Here is my file.

```
    $client_id = $jsonDecode['client_id'];
    $Email_address = $jsonDecode['client_email'];    
    $key_file_location = 'privateKey.p12';      

    $client = new Google_Client();      
    $client->setApplicationName("<APP NAME>");
    $key = file_get_contents($key_file_location);    

// separate additional scopes with a comma   
$scopes ="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly";   
$cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(    
    $Email_address,      
    array($scopes),     
    $key         
    );      
$client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);
if($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {        
    $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred);       
}       

$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
```